# Matlab GUIDE appearance change with screen magnification

Tags: windows, matlab, matlab-guide

Developing using Matlab 2014b's GUIDE, some of my GUIs have elements with units specified as "characters". Depending on the screen magnification level in Windows 7 (Control Panel>Appearance>Display) the GUI will look very different, with elements scattered. Shouldn't using characters as the unit type make adapting to the screen magnification a piece of cake, since the system character size would change I believe?

I'd rather not need to hard-code the units as pixels or etc, so that the GUI is happy being used on Windows/Linux/Mac. Anyone have any experiences/ suggestions with this?

Comment: Have you tried using the normalized setting, instead of characters?

Comment: Using normalized helped somewhat in one case, but things were still differently sized between magnifications.

Answer (score 0):

I have found it is easiest to use pixels. You can then get the current window size and set things as percentages (from variables) of the real pixel dimensions. This is nice when you want to make sure there is a minimum or maximum panel or item size that can be resized or scaled within a range.

If you put this code in the resizeFcn() it should be good.